# WebGL support in TideSDK

Tags: webkit, webgl, tidesdk

Does the webkit view used by TideSDK have WebGL support enabled?

Would it also be possible to configure the web view to use native OpenGL on Windows instead of ANGLE emulation for the shaders? (like the way you can start Chrome with the --use-gl=desktop option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are close to getting webgl support.

Follow [this issue](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues/25)

Looks like it will be supported in 1.4 release according to their [blog](http://www.tidesdk.org/blog/). I haven't found an expected release date for it yet